# Deploying WebApi and Angular to IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, deployment

I have 2 projects a WebApi in .Net Framwork 4.8 and a angular front end. In the past i have deployed to apache with a reverse proxy to the API. I am curious if there is a better way of achieving this on IIS, I need to log referrer and its already becoming problematic.

I have also been looking at using MS deploy, but have no experience as of this post using it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it seems that the webapi and the angular application is not in a same project.

I suggest you could create a web site in the IIS and publish the whole asp.net web api to the IIS by using web deploy. Details ,you could refer to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/publish-and-host-Asp-Net-web-api/).

> In the past i have deployed to apache with a reverse proxy to the API.

IIS could also enable the reverse proxy, you could use url rewrite to achieve this. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/).

Besides, you could directly convert the nginx .htaccess proxy rule to IIS web.config url rewrite rule by using IIS url rewrite build-in feature.

[image]